# Gnuplot -- Incomplete Beta Function with Parameter Zero

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot the incomplete beta function (alternatively, the hypergeometric function), and preferably in `gnuplot`. However, the built-in `ibeta` function seems to be rather off. For example, compare this result of
`plot ibeta(.1,1,x) lw 3` :
[image]

with the result from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20Beta%5Bx%2C.1%2C1%5D%20%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D):
[image]

Similar discrepancies arise for other values of the parameters `p` and `q`. The documentation does not offer much help.

So:

- Am I missing something obvious?
- Is there a better implementation? Ideally one that can handle `q=0`, i.e. `ibeta(.1,0,x)`?
- Alternatively, is there a better way to plot a hypergeometric function `2F1(1,b;1+b;x)`?

Comment: The normalized incomplete beta function by definition must lie between 0 and 1.  I don't know what you plotted in in Wolfram Alpha but it must have been something else.

Comment: @Ethan Well, maybe that's what I'm missing: You're saying that `ibeta` is the "normalised" (presumably aka regularised) incomplete beta function (i.e. ibeta(p,q,x)=inc_beta(x,p,q)/inc_beta(1,p,q)) ? The incomplete beta function itself is not bounded between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Ethan You're right, `ibeta`is the regularised incomplete beta function. The full incomplete beta function is obtained by unnormalising it, e.g. `ibeta(.1,1,x)*gamma(.1)*gamma(1)/gamma(1.1)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I can answer my question due to he comment by Ethan:

Gnuplot's `ibeta`function is the "regularised incomplete beta function", i.e. the incomplete beta function divided by the complete beta funcion of `p` and `q`. To obtain the actual incomplete beta function, multiply by the beta function, which can be expressed by the gamma functions as `beta(p,q)=gamma(p)*gamma(q)/gamma(p+q)`.  Then the results agree with e.g. Wolfram Alpha.

However, there is a new probem, which I discuss in a new question.

(There does not seem to be a math mode in this stack exchange?)